# Is it possible to build a Native App with React-Native, Vue.js and Laravel combined?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js

Is it possible to build a Native App with React-Native, Vue.js and Laravel combined?

- Laravel (Backend)
- Vue.js (Front-end Javascript)
- React-Native (Native App support for iOS and Android)

Or would you run into any issues or conflicts with Vue.js combined with React-Native?

Answer (score 0):

https://vue-native.io/

Vue Native is a framework to build cross platform native mobile apps using JavaScript